# Void* when allocating

Tags: c, memory, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, void

When is it appropriate to use

```
void* space_to_use = malloc(size);
```

Comment: Impossible to copy-paste whole C book. Get any book, answer is at first 10 pages.

Comment: can be anything you want

Comment: It is difficult to infer the purpose of using memory chunks from this code piece. Perhaps it is not intended for specific use.

Comment: Yup - maybe it's just 'data'.  Maybe the code is just loading it from some stream, and passing it on.  It doesn't need to know what's in the buffer.

Comment: _Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [Ask] page for help clarifying this question._

Comment: probably always, probably never....what's the requirement?

Comment: It's kind of rude to completely change your question after answers have been submitted, because now the answers do not make sense.

Comment: Some context of where you found this code is necessary to answer.

Comment: @JohnBode Can't agree more, but the fundamental problem is, questions like this should not be answered, at all. It's waste of effort, overall.

Comment: I am sorry, but I can't delete the question.

Comment: You could try unchecking the "accept answer".

Comment: ...and then see if you can delete the question.

Comment: Even without the checked answer, it is impossible because of all the answers this question got.

Comment: @KarinaK You could attempt to modify and improve the question, for example by including the surrounding code where you found this line. Questions are closed and not deleted to give the poster a chance to improve them, if possible. Otherwise if nothing is changed and there are no up-voted answers, a closed question will eventually get deleted automatically by the scripts on the site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
void* space_to_use = malloc(size); 
// malloc always return void pointer that means it can be typecast to any type.
// before using void pointer it is necessary to typecast it into proper type.
// for example:-
// if size is 8 byte.It will allocate 8 byte of memory.
/*
void* space_to_use = malloc(size); 
char * ptr = (char*)space_to_use;
*/
// These two line can be combine in one statement.

char * ptr = (char*)malloc(size*sizeeof(char));
// NOTE:sizeof(char) is to make sure platform independent.

// Same for int if we want to store some integer.
 int * ptr = (int*)malloc(size*sizeeof(int));
```

Comment: Just for information: `sizeof char` is defined to always be `1` so there's never a need to muliply by it. However, the `CHAR_BIT` define can be different.

Comment: Also please see [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Yes it will be always one byte but it will generic means for integer for integer * or structure varaibe or pointer.We need to add sizeof(int) or sizeof(int *) or sizeof(strcuct abcd) so if we mention sizeof(char) it will not harm anything.